# uploadify - show uploaded images on page

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, uploadify

I'm building a site (in php) that uses uploadify to allow a user to upload portfolio images.

I have uploadify working fine, but I'm just wondering the best way of showing the uploaded images on the page once they have been uploaded. Is it possible to do without a page refresh?

I've pasted my uploadify code below:

```
<script>
    <?php $timestamp = time();?>
        var counter = 1;
        $(function() {
            $('#file_upload').uploadifive({ 
            onUploadComplete: function(event, queueID, fileObj, reponse, data) {
                //alert(counter);
                counter = counter +1 ;
                     },
                'buttonText'   : 'Upload Images...',
                'uploadLimit'  : 12,
                'uploadScript' : '/includes/uploadifive.php',
                'checkScript'  : '/includes/check-exists.php',
                'auto'         : true,
                'method'       : 'post',
                formData     : { 
                    'page_id' : '<? echo $pageDetails->row['page_id'] ?>',
                    'counter'    : counter,
                    'timestamp'  : '<? echo $timestamp;?>',
                    'token'      : '<? echo md5('unique_salt' . $timestamp);?>'
                 },


            });
        });
        </script>
```

I'm not too sure how to get the file name from uploadify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can just add `img` elements to the page dynamically via the DOM:

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = "/path/to/the/new/img.png";
document.getElementById("somecontainer").appendChild(img);
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/ipivat/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ipivat/1/edit)

You may need to do an ajax call to the server to get the path of the new image, unless that falls out naturally from your application logic.

Answer (score 0):

In the edition I use there is a function

```
onUploadSuccess : function(file,data,response){
}
```

Then I can get file name by file.name;
So in your code maybe the fileObj, You can try fileObj.name to get the name of the file you upload.